# Tes case Getting failed after closing the Pop Up window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup, window

I am implementing POM with page factory in my project
and i am facing an issue

there is a page in the application inside this page "folder" link exist when i click on this a pop up gets open
i have to search a folder and select this (entering foldername ,select radio button ,click on go button)
which is i am able to do but when i click on Go button after fill all the data for this pop up
this pop up get closed and selected data display on the main page but after this my next command is not getting executed like fill the value in the next fileds.

i am calling below method in the my test page

```
public void TabHandles() throws Throwable {

    String currentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

    //Get the list of all window handles
    ArrayList<String> windowHandles = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());

    for (String window:windowHandles){

    //if it contains the current window we want to eliminate that from switchTo();
    if (window != currentWindowHandle)
    {
    //Now switchTo new Tab.
    driver.switchTo().window(window);
    //Do whatever you want to do here.
    //driver.close();


    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }

public ProfilePage CompleteUccForm() throws Throwable {

    test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Cliking in the UCC Tab");
    //upload.click();


    ucc.click();

    folder.click();


    //newttab();

    tabHandles();

    foldertext.sendKeys("Applesamsung");
    foldergo.click();
    folderradio.click();
    folderselect.click();

    // maintabttab();

    realestatecheck.click();
    contactname.sendKeys("deepak");
    relation.sendKeys("Lessee/Lessor");
```

and my test case is getting failed. with the Below error ---

```
FAILED: CompleteUccForm-
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'DS-E0699598D816', ip: '10.97.222.20', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=37.0.2, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 6ca9a623-ea39-4c16-a7dd-e1b3f80afd04
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id='ctrlLien_lienHeadercontrol_chkFixture']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Please reply i am stuck in this  problem since long time

Comment: Please format you post properly, there might be some copy-paste errors already.

Answer (score 1):

After the popup window close you need to run SwitchTo command again to switch to whichever window you need and then the web driver will able to find the elements and perform actions which you need.

P.S : Before the popup window appear store the Window Id in some string variable it will be easy again switch back once the popup window closes.

Answer (score 0):

After `driver.close();` perform `driver.switchTo().window(currentWindowHandle);`

It'll do the work.